# Is size for the same file identical on different Android devices?

Tags: android

I am using `File.length()` to get file size, and I hardcoded file sizes in an array in app. If the file (downloaded file) is not the same size of recorded size, I delete it and request user to download it again.

Is this correct? if not what is the best approach to validate downloaded file?

**Can file length be different per device / android version?**

Comment: Usually, people use something like an md5 checksum to check for a downloaded file's authenticity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A downloaded file length will not be different per device / android version, not unless you have written a compression code or any modification of the image.**

Now as for the approach, yes the approach is correct. But it's all about the underlying algorithm used. Algorithms vary, some increases the precision. You can read about `File.length()` [here at the Androdid Developers Page.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length())

Then decide if that's what you want to use, or another logic written by you or someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify file checksum. 2 files can have same length but contain different data.

> Can file length be different per device / android version?

If you are saving it as binary file - no, it's plain data.